# URL-based redirect with Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have several domain aliases pointing to the same website like:

domain1.de/en/

domain1.de/de/

domain2.ch/de/

domain2.ch/en/

When someone opens a specific language-based sub-directory on a URL, I would like to redirect them to the start page, e.g. for domain1.de users shouldn't be able to access the sub-directory /en/ but be redirected to the start page. For the domain2.ch users should only have access to the directory /en/ and not /de/. How can I set this up with Htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a helpful link to you;

[htaccess redirect](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/index.php)

for a 301 redirect entire directory it generated the following code:

```
//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 domain2.ch/de/(.*) domain2.ch/en//$1
RedirectMatch 301 domain1.de/de/(.*) domain1.de/en//$1
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately it is not working. I have now tried at least 30 codes and all doesn't do what I want. I think it must be something like this here:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^de\.domain1\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^en/$ http://de.domain1.de/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

First check that the domain alias exactly matches and then redirect the whole directory to the start page. However it doesn't work ...

Comment: Does anyone know how conditional redirect rules depending on the domain can be defined in htaccess, e.g. only for domain xyz.com the subdirectory /aa/ shall be redirected to the root directory or a specific URL?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^de\.domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/en/(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/targetpage.php [R=301,L]
```